# Как просмотреть данные передаваемые HTTP-методом GET

Tags: django, веб-программирование, get

Учусь веб-разработке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как просмотреть данные передаваемые методом `GET` и как посмотреть, какие данные необходимо получить для корректной работы страницы? (может есть возможность смотреть через браузер?)

Использую Дебиан, PyCharm, Django

Comment: Очень мало информации с вопросом - откуда передаете, куда и как - программно, али нет. Учитесь писать развёрнутые вопросы чтобы было меньше учтоняющих комментариев - это полезно и вам, и сообществу.

Comment: `как посмотреть, какие данные необходимо получить для корректной работы страницы?` Вот это вот вообще непонятно. Видимо нужно смотреть в код обработчика страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно через браузер посмотреть. Выбираете "инструменты разработчика" - F12 часто, дальше "сеть" или "веб-консоль". Там все http-запросы можно рассмотреть подробно.

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо!